# html img - no image error - image flickers

Tags: html, angular, image

I am displaying a 'no image found' image when the original image fails to show up.

The src of the img is updated very rapidly (in every few milliseconds). So,when an image with a failed src shows up, the error image is displayed but it flickers due to rapid updates. (ie. the src is updated with the same error url, rapidly)

Here is the code

```
<img src="{{imgSrc}}{{car.modelNum | carName:car.code}}" onerror="this.src='assets/images/no-car-image.jpg';"    />
```

The model Car is updated rapidly but the modelNum and car code is the same over updates. Hence the URL will also be same.

Is there any way to control the ui updates in angular when the data is not actually changed on updates?

Update Jan25,2023 - This image is inside an *ngFor

Comment: Use `ng-src` not `src`.

Comment: I am sorry, I am on Angular, not AngularJS. updated question tag

Answer (score 0):

i guess "ng-if" || "ng-show" directives could solve your problem by showing || declaring img tag when actual data to show is ready...

Declare image when "data_is_loaded" = Positive Value || True

```
<img ng-if="data_is_loaded" src="{{imgSrc}}{{car.modelNum | carName:car.code}}" onerror="this.src='assets/images/no-car-image.jpg';"    />
```

Show image when "data_is_loaded" = Positive Value || True (note that this one is declared but is hidden...)

```
<img ng-show="data_is_loaded" src="{{imgSrc}}{{car.modelNum | carName:car.code}}" onerror="this.src='assets/images/no-car-image.jpg';"    />
```

and the value of "data_is_loaded" could be set when your image finally loaded or failed...